# How are YouTube Playback Locations and Traffic Sources determined?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm hoping someone from YouTube might shed a bit of light on this question.  I'm wondering what information is used to determine the Playback Location and Traffic Source?  Are these simply the document.location.href and document.location.referer?  Or are HTTP referrer headers used (which can vary by browser)?

The reason for the question is basically around SEO, and just trying to understand how some of these "attribution" decisions are made.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's more info: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims#insightTrafficSourceDetail. If you embed a video in your web application and don't see the EXT_URL properly reflected please file a bug using the process described here: https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow_14.html.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on this a bit, in case something happens to that link...